# Used malwarebytes now i have missing .dlls

Tags: anti-virus

I did a maleware search and got  rid of  few trogans but now I kep getting messages like error in C:\documents and settings\lindam\application\ntcdsr.dll miss entry

c:\documents and settings\lindam]application\ntcdsr.dll

c:\documents and settings\lindam]application\ipsuiz.dll missing

How do i fix this..

Comment: I just deleted the keys in regedit by doing a search.. Ex ipsuiz.dll find  command in regedit. Right away i found the .dll keys in question. I deleted and boom it worked. I did more scans and i`m coming up clean even after reboots. I agree with the restore option but thats a lot of down time on a pay role day.. I`m 99.9  sure there is no other problems.

Answer (score 3):

When your computer is infected you can never trust it to work correctly ever again. You should have reinstalled Windows in the first place, and you should still reinstall Windows now.

PS> Those errors look **very much like the virus** trying to reinstall itself. You're almost certainly **still infected**. This is exactly why you need to **wipe** the computer, **restore** important files from backup, and **never trust** a computer that's been infected.

Comment: kinda hard to do when its a server

Comment: Your *Disaster Recovery Plan* should include directions for reinstall the server and recovering files from backup (even if they're in broad strokes). Reinstalling Windows should *never* be "hard to do" for a System Administrator. I'll only write this one sentence wondering what someone was doing with a server that it got infected. Nothing will change the fact that you should have reinstalled, and it's still the correct course of action.

Comment: The owner sent something to an employee and it was a virus.. The owners home comeputer got infected. We have back ups up i`m not sure when the computer got infected.

Comment: ok for people not wanting to do a complete restore. Just search the .ll in question in regedit and delete the items you find. Make sure there not to tied to anything important.